# Define a XLISP function, rev-rest, that reverses all but the first element of a list

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

Define a xlisp  function, rev-rest, that reverses all but  the first  element of a list.   That is, (rev-rest ‘(a b c d e))should  return (a e d c b).

I was only able to code this because I am not sure what to use at all to get the last four to be in reverse.

```
(defun rev-rest '(a b c d e))
(write (rev-rest ))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, that function would look like this:

```
(defun rev-rest (lst)
  (if (null lst) lst
    (cons (car lst)
          (reverse (cdr lst)))))
```

Function with one argument (named lst). If lst is empty list, it's returned. Else function creates new list ([CONS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons.htm)) from first element of lst ([CAR](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm#car)) and rest of elements of lst ([CDR](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm#cdr)), which were reversed (expecting that you can use built-in [REVERSE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm)).
Then you call it this way:

```
(rev-rest '(a b c d e))
```

XLISP contains all these functions, so it should be same.